# jquery scroll to element then lock to that element regardless of changes on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to scroll to a specific element inside of a wrapping element. It works as I intended it to work, as long as the screen width isn't resized. As soon as the screen width changes, the scroll doesn't stick. Here are my current code:

**Javascript**

```
function pageInit(pageId)
{
    $('.page-wrapper').animate({ scrollLeft: $('#' + pageId).offset().left }, 500);
    $('#' + pageId).css('postion', 'fixed');
    console.debug('Page #' + pageId + ' initiated.');
}

pageInit('about');
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
<div class="page main-page" id="root" data-pos="0">
    <div class="group-container">
        <div class="book"></div>
        <div class="promo">
            <div class="button">
                <a href="/about">
                <div class="button-logo cover-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">Read the summary</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                <div class="button-logo yt-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">Watch the trailer</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                <div class="button-logo wattpad-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">Coming soon on Wattpad</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="//localhost/internals/close_tab" target="twitter">
                <div class="button-logo twitter-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">#Ghifari160sBeingTheOne</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="//localhost/internals/close_tab" target="facebook">
                <div class="button-logo facebook-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">Share it on Facebook</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page about-page" id="about" data-pos="100">
    <div class="group-container">
        <div class="summary">
            %Summary%
        </div>
        <div class="promo">
            <div class="button">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                <div class="button-logo yt-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">Watch the trailer</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                <div class="button-logo wattpad-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">Coming soon on Wattpad</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="//localhost/internals/close_tab" target="twitter">
                <div class="button-logo twitter-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">#Ghifari160sBeingTheOne</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="//localhost/internals/close_tab" target="facebook">
                <div class="button-logo facebook-button-logo"></div>
                <div class="button-text">Share it on Facebook</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The wrapping element should be scrolled to the right until the element with the id of "about" fills the entire screen. My current code works perfectly for that part. I just need to find a way to do the same thing when the screen width changes, that way the "about" element always fills the entire screen. I've tried checking every few seconds and rescroll to the element if the screen width change, but it fails every once in awhile. Is there any way that I can make the browser scroll to the element I intended it to scroll to, then rescroll to that element after detecting changes on screen width?

**EDIT:**
JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ghifari160/sy3qgtqe/1/

Comment: Could you perhaps create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of this?

Comment: is there a reason why you're using regular links in the href? if you just want it to point somewhere on the same page you should use #about instead

Comment: it's just for illusion effects. A lot of sites do this, and it works well. My problem has nothing to do with that. Also, what's not shown on the code snippets is that the links are actually bound to a function that will check whether it is an internal link and take the appropriate actions (scroll to #about, change the url box to /about, and of course, return false to prevent default link handling).

Answer (score 0):

The question is difficult to answer clearly since there's no way for us to see the results without a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or [pen](http://www.codepen.io). But, considering you're needing to trigger an event on a window resize, you should look at the [window.resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) global event handler.

Window.resize is an event handler like any other, so use your pageInit() function as the callback parameter for the handler. Make sure to still call your function an initial time, otherwise your function won't run *until* the window has been resized.

Edit: might as well add an example for clarity.

```js
window.onresize = pageInit('about');
```

Comment: I did as explained (if I understand correctly), but the page keeps scrolling indefinitely. I created a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ghifari160/sy3qgtqe/1/